# Adding series to Pandas dataframe yields column of NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Using this data set (some cols and hundreds of rows omitted for brevity) . . .

```
    Year    Ceremony    Award          Winner   Name    
0   1927/1928   1       Best Actress    0.0     Louise Dresser  
1   1927/1928   1       Best Actress    1.0     Janet Gaynor
2   1937        10      Best Actress    0.0     Janet Gaynor
3   1927/1928   1       Best Actress    0.0     Gloria Swanson  
4   1929/1930   3       Best Actress    0.0     Gloria Swanson
5   1950        23      Best Actress    0.0     Gloria Swanson
```

I used the following command . . .

```
ba_dob.loc[ba_dob.Winner == 0.0, :].groupby('Name').Winner.count()
```

To create the following series . . .

```
Name
Ali MacGraw                1
Amy Adams                  1
Angela Bassett             1
Angelina Jolie             1
Anjelica Huston            1
Ann Harding                1
Ann-Margret                1
Anna Magnani               1
Anne Bancroft              4
Anne Baxter                1
Anne Hathaway              1
Annette Bening             3
Audrey Hepburn             4
```

I tried adding the series to the original dataframe like so . . .

```
ba_dob['New_Col'] = ba_dob.loc[ba_dob.Winner == 0.0, :].groupby('Name').Winner.count()
```

I got an column of NaN values.

I've read the other posts suggesting that there might be some faulty indexing at work, but I'm not sure how that would shake out. More specifically, why would Pandas not be able to line up the indexes, as the groupby and count are coming from the same table. Is there something else afoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), not [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html), because `count` exclude `NaN`s:

Last [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) column `Name` by `Series` created by `groupby`:

```
m = ba_dob.Winner == 0.0
ba_dob['new'] = ba_dob['Name'].map(ba_dob[m].groupby('Name').Winner.size())
print (ba_dob)
        Year  Ceremony         Award  Winner            Name  new
0  1927/1928         1  Best Actress     0.0  Louise Dresser    1
1  1927/1928         1  Best Actress     1.0    Janet Gaynor    1
2       1937        10  Best Actress     0.0    Janet Gaynor    1
3  1927/1928         1  Best Actress     0.0  Gloria Swanson    3
4  1929/1930         3  Best Actress     0.0  Gloria Swanson    3
5       1950        23  Best Actress     0.0  Gloria Swanson    3
```

Another solution:

```
ba_dob['new'] = ba_dob['Name'].map(ba_dob.loc[m, 'Name'].value_counts())
```

Comment: Impressive. I was not aware of either the transform function or the notion that you could ask .loc for a column you had not yet created.

Comment: It provides much to think about though.

Comment: Give me a sec, I have an idea

Comment: Ended up using this implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can join your result on the initial data frame

```
New_col = df.loc[df.Winner == 0.0, :].groupby('Name').Winner.count().rename('New_col')
df = df.join(New_col, on='Name')
```

Output :

```
    Award           Ceremony    Name            Winner  Year New_col
0   Best Actress    1927/1928   Louise Dresser  0.0     0    1
1   Best Actress    1927/1928   Janet Gaynor    1.0     1    1
2   Best Actress    1937        Janet Gaynor    0.0     2    1
3   Best Actress    1927/1928   Gloria Swanson  0.0     3    3
4   Best Actress    1929/1930   Gloria Swanson  0.0     4    3
5   Best Actress    1950        Gloria Swanson  0.0     5    3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use map

```
mapper = ba_dob.loc[ba_dob.Winner == 0.0, :].groupby('Name').Winner.count()
ba_dob['New_Col'] = ba_dob['Name'].map(mapper)
```

You get

```
    Year        Ceremony    Award       Winner  Name            New_Col
0   1927/1928   1           BestActress 0.0     Louise Dresser  1
1   1927/1928   1           BestActress 1.0     Janet Gaynor    1
2   1937        10          BestActress 0.0     Janet Gaynor    1
3   1927/1928   1           BestActress 0.0     Gloria Swanson  3
4   1929/1930   3           BestActress 0.0     Gloria Swanson  3
5   1950        23          BestActress 0.0     Gloria Swanson  3
```

Comment: Very nice and many thanks! Could you elaborate on the last line before I accept?

Comment: Pandas provides a function map (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) using which you can map values of a series (ba_dob['Name']) to another series (count). Its a very useful function, you can also use it with a dictionary as a mapper.

Comment: Do take a look at @jezrael's answer, you may want to use size instead of count to include all the rows

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to use reset_index() ,which removes hierarchy and creates two fields Name & Count.Post that select 'Count' field to add it to dataframe. Something like

```
 ba_dob['New_Col'] = ba_dob.loc[ba_dob.Winner == 0.0, :].groupby('Name').Winner.count().reset_index()['count']
```

Comment: Hmm. KeyError for some reason. But you do think indexing is the issue.

Comment: oh.on second thoughts, it wouldn't work as resetting the index will imply not able to map to the original index of the dataframe.My bad

Answer (score 0):

Your `groupby` does not cover the entire `DataFrame` but only the rows where `Winner == 0`, so of course for these rows you will get `NaN`.

Comment: While this makes sense, what I observed was a column of `NaNs` straight down the line. No exceptions.

Comment: @Ryan you need to be careful with doing ``==`` on float, it might appear as ``0.0`` but it is ``0.0001`` etc.  Basically, verify your filter is working, and add an ``epsilon`` if needed.